# How do I merge two large data.frames using ff package in R?

Tags: r, join, large-data

I have two very large .csv files, let us call them CSV.1 and CSV.2 (CSV.1 is about 1.4 GB, and CSV.2 is about 790 MB), and I would like to join them using a FULL OUTER JOIN on the common field "Id".  The CSV files' fields are of multiple types, some are entirely numeric, others are character strings.  Also, CSV.1 has around 190 columns and 1.6 million records, CSV.2 has about 40 columns and 570k records.

Initially, I wrote and executed the following code:

```
first_csv <- read.csv("CSV.1")
second_csv <- read.csv("CSV.2")
joined_csv <- join(CSV.1, CSV.2, by="Id", type="full")
```

However, this returned the typical, Your RAM is completely taxed, error.  So I tried the following:

```
# Install and invoke the ff package
install.packages("ff")
library(ff)
library(plyr)

# Read in the data
first_csv <- read.csv("CSV.1")
second_csv <- read.csv("CSV.2")

# Convert dataframes to ffdf's, while freeing up memory
first_csv_ff <- as.ffdf(first_csv)
rm(first_csv)
gc()
second_csv_ff <- as.ffdf(second_csv)
rm(second_csv)
gc()

# Attempt to join the two ffdf's by "Id"
joined_csv <- join(first_csv_ff, second_csv_ff, by="Id", type="full")
```

R croaks out the following error:

```
Error in as.hi.integer(x, maxindex = maxindex, dim = dim, vw = vw, pack = pack) : 
NAs in as.hi.integer
```

I also tried, the " <- ffdf() " without the as.ffdf, but there was no joy there either.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` of `ff` package, FYI:

```
FULL Outer join ~ merge(x = df1, y = df2, ...., all = TRUE)
```

With your data , this should work :

```
merge(first_csv_ff, second_csv_ff, by="Id", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, that's definitely good to know, but for some reason (even after converting to ff) I get:    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 555.1 Mb


Maybe I should ask this as a separate question now, that I have your answer, but shouldn't ff handle the memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

ffbase package provides the basic statistical functions for ff package.

```
install.packages(ffbase)
require(ffbase)
#now perform the merge
merge(ffdf1,ffdf2,by="key")
```